# jQuery if coupon code added in WooCommerce

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

Thanks in advance for ANY help.

Weird one, my client whom I have set up a WooCommerce website with wants to sell only products through their personal trainers, but allow any user to see them.

So I'm not sure of the best way to approach this. I was thinking of using the Coupon code input and doing some sort of check to see if the user added a specific code into it then show the shop purchase buttons, or else show a message like 'Your trainer needs to buy these!'

Thanks
GB

Comment: Maybe only allow certain user groups to see the purchase buttons and check out? Or only users in general, and have no option for sign up?

Comment: can't you customize that in user preferences? so for each user you create you can either choose to give them order placing privileges or not

Comment: Are the users allowed to create an account? Is there users that have already accounts? How you distinguish users from trainers? are the trainers known yet?

Comment: Thanks all for comments. The trainers are not really known yet but I think the best way is what has been suggested, allow only users registered so 'customers' to get to the checkout page and make a purchase. Thanks for your help.